# I am unable to run and debug flutter app in VS code and whenever I try running it I get following error

Tags: android, flutter

- I am using Flutter 0.9.4 • channel beta
- Android Studio 3.2.1
- VS Code 1.28.2

Whenever I try to debug and run my app it shows following error msg:

[image]

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Custom Phone, 8 0, API 26, 768x1280 in debug mode...
* Error running Gradle:
Exit code 1 from: C:\Users\Ketan\Documents\Flutter\hello\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Ketan\Documents\Flutter\hello\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
   > Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Comment: `Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).`... This means the `repositories` section of your Gradle file could not download this file...

Comment: I get that but how to fix it :D

Comment: Do you have `google()` listed in your repositories? Based on the error, looks like you only have `jcenter()`

Comment: Thank You so much. Indeed google() was missing.

Comment: I know Android Studio sets that up for new Android projects.. Not sure about Flutter

Answer (score 0):

Try this from  [flutter documentation:](https://flutter.io/setup-windows/)

**Update your path**

If you wish to run Flutter commands in the regular Windows command prompt, take these steps to add Flutter to the PATH environment variable:

- Go to

> “Control Panel > User Accounts > User Accounts > Change my environment
> variables”

- Under “User variables” check if there is an entry called “Path”:
- If the entry does exist, append the full path to `flutter\bin` using ; as a separator from existing values.
- If the entry does not exist, create a new user variable named Path with the full `path` to `flutter\bin` as its value.
  Reboot Windows to fully apply this change.

Comment: I already have path set up, it was the small bug with flutter.gradle which is located in flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle . After editing it VS code is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: @KetanRamteke You can add it as an accepted answer so that it would be helpful in future for others( like me :P) :)